# reload data never stops in tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, reload

I want to reload the data in tableview when I finish the query in Parse.com but once it starts reloading, it never stops. 
Here's the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    WishlistCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" ];
    wishlist *temp=(wishlist*)[_dataSource objectAtIndex:[indexPath indexAtPosition:1]];
    PFQuery * retrieveExpos = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
    [retrieveExpos whereKey:@"username" equalTo:temp.exponom];
    [retrieveExpos findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",objects);
        if (!error) {
            exposArray =[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        }
    }];

    PFQuery * retrieveImage = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"CarDescription"];
    [retrieveImage whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:temp.idvoiture];
    [retrieveImage findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects1, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",objects1);
        if (!error) {

            exposArray1 =[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects1];

        }
        [tableview reloadData];

    }];

    PFObject * tempObject = [exposArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.EXPONAME.text=[tempObject objectForKey:@"Exponame"];
    cell.PHONENUMBER.text=[tempObject objectForKey:@"Number"];
    PFObject * tempObject1 = [exposArray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PFFile * imageFile= [tempObject1 objectForKey:@"FrontImage"];
    cell.loadingSpinner.hidden=NO;

    [cell.loadingSpinner startAnimating];
    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            //                       NSLog(@"%@",data);
            cell.CarImage.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
            [cell.loadingSpinner stopAnimating];
            cell.loadingSpinner.hidden=YES;
        }
    }];
    return  cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you run into an never-ending recursion

`reloadData` makes tableView to build it up again. One of the last steps is to create cells for all visible rows. in `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, where you trigger `reloadData` again (although it is deferred in a block) — resulting in a circle.

Another issue could be that you call `[tableView reloadData]` in a background thread. UI in general has to happen on the main thread.

Comment: Thank You for your help, I just added a condition to stop the loop.